# Can you earn the BF Drill as a Series EV?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

On the BF Drill page on the dungeon defenders wiki http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/The_BF_Drill it states that you have to be a Huntress or Ranger to get the BF Drill from the Volcanic Eruption map. Can you also get it as a Series EV? I really don't want to have to lvl up a huntress to 74.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Series EV](http://www.dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Series_EV) can use huntress **and** apprentice weapons, so yes you can use that weapon on your Series EV.  As such, you have a chance to get either the apprentice or the huntress weapon each time you complete the challenge.

Comment: I asked could you EARN it as a Series EV, sorry. I edited my Q to make it clearer

Comment: What do you mean by earn it?

Comment: You get the BF Drill if you complete the Volcanic Eruption Challenge map (or something like that) you get the BF Drill as a Huntress/Ranger but on the wiki it doesn't state if you can get it with the Series EV

Comment: Ahh. Well I did some more research and its random. You have a chance to get either the apprentice or the huntress weapon each time you complete the challenge. Sorry for the confusion!